# Back Navigation Button not showing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic / Angularjs and learning to use it.

I'm fetching menu links from server and on clicking, it goes to detail page but Back button not showing. It is working in Tab Menu example from ionic. 
Also when i click browser Back Button, it shows on Homepage (I don't think it should show?)
Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

Codes are as below:

Controller.js

```
angular.module('GAC.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, pagesService) {
    //GET PAGE LIST
    pagesService.fetchFromServer().then( function(list){
        $scope.pageList = list; 
    });

})
.controller('PageCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, pagesService) {
    if(!isNaN(parseInt($stateParams.pageId))){
        pagesService.fetchById( $stateParams.pageId ).then(function(page){
            $scope.page = page; 
        }); 
    }else{
        alert('No Such Page'); // How to redirect to Homepage   
    }
})
.factory('pagesService', ['$http', function( $http ){
    var service = {};
    service.fetchFromServer = function( ){
        var promise = $http.jsonp('http://m.aboudcar.com/server/pages/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
                        .then( function(response ){
                            return response.data;   
                        })
        return promise;                         
    };
    service.fetchById = function( pageId ){
        var promise = $http.jsonp('http://m.aboudcar.com/server/pages/fetchbyid/'+pageId+'?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
                        .then( function(response ){
                            return response.data;   
                        })
        return promise;                         
    };

    return service;
}])
```

App.js

```
angular.module('GAC', ['ionic', 'GAC.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.cars', {
      url: "/cars",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/cars.html",
          controller: 'CarsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.single', {
      url: "/pages/:pageId",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/page.html",
          controller: 'PageCtrl'
        }
      }
    });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/cars');
});
```

Menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </header>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-list>
      <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-repeat="page in pageList" href="{{page.url}}">
          {{page.name}}
       </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Page.html

```
<ion-view title="{{page.name}}">
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <h1>{{page.name}}</h1>
    {{page.content}} 
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Please provide code related to the problem or (even better) link to a working jsfiddle/codepen.

Comment: ok added codes. please check above. thanx

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem. Don't just dump your whole application here.

Comment: It is as min as possible, i mean for pages section only. so have hidden other codes.